# C# deserialize XML

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have problem with deserialize document to object using `XmlSerializer` class.

Code my function for deserialize:

```
   static public TYPE xmlToObject<TYPE>( string xmlDoc ) {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] xmlObject = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes( xmlDoc );
        stream.Write( xmlObject, 0, xmlObject.Length );
        stream.Position = 0;

        TYPE message;

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( TYPE ) );

        try {
            message = (TYPE)xmlSerializer.Deserialize( stream );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            message = default( TYPE );
        } finally {
            stream.Close();
        }
        return message;
    }
```

And I have class:

```
    public class Test {
           public int a;
           public int b;
    }
```

And deserialize:

```
    string text = File.ReadAllText( "blue1.xml" );
    Test a = XmlInterpreter.xmlToObject<Test>( text );
```

Ok, when I read file like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Test>
       <a>2</a>
       <b>5</b>
    </Test>
```

everything is OK. But like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Test>
        <a>2</a>
        <b></b>
    </Test>
```

is wrong because

```
    <b></b>
```

is empty and conversion into int is impossible.

How can I solve this? For example I want in this context that `b` will be not declared.

What when my class is:

```
    public class Test {

        public enum Pro {
             VALUE1,
             VALUE2
        }

        public Pro p1;
   }
```

And I want accept `xmlDocument`, where field `p1` is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect that first example is just some type because it has empty `b` as well. First of all not every XML can be deserialized to object. Especially empty elements are dangerous and should not be used. If you want to express that `b` is not defined then do not include it in XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test>
    <a>2</a>
</Test>
```

or make your b property nullable:

```
public class Test {
       public int a;
       public int? b;
}
```

and define XML as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a>2</a>
    <b xsi:nil="true" />
</Test>
```

Generally if you want to use deserialization try to first use serialization to understand how must a valid XML look like.